# What happens when you hibernate with more memory than your SSD?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, ssd, hibernate

Lets say if you have 16 Gigabytes of RAM and hibernate when you have an 8 Gigabyte SSD. Since hibernation dumps the ram contents to the SSD, what would happen?

Comment: When you enable hibernation it reserves the required disk space.

Comment: @DavidPostill, would it do so on the hard disk automatically, seeing that it wouldn't fit on the SSD ?

Comment: But if all 16GB are used and somehow you have an 8GB how would hibernation work? What gets saved? Or is this example so theoretical it makes no practical sense since larger SSDs are cheap and plentiful nowadays. So realistically a 32GB SSD would be the smallest one would be able to get.

Comment: If the required free space is not available it will not allow you to enable hibernation.